# WildFly 8 on Eclipse - Necessary install all JBoss tools plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I have recently moved to JDK 8 and want to start developing applications and have a server, wildfly. In NetBeans you just have to import the WildFly plugin, but in eclipse you have to import all JBoss Tools plugins. You need to install ~ 450MB (JBoss Tools) only for use WildFly 8? WildFly 8 has depends on all these plugins?

Greetings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to install all of JBoss Tools. There is a feature category called **Abridged JBoss Tools**. which contains the absolute minimum feature **JBossAS Tools**, which is basically a WTP adapter for JBoss AS/WildFly.

Note that there *is* some useful stuff in the Abridged Tools, like extended JSF and CDI support for Eclipse. But for stuff like Seam or Portlets which you probably don't use, it's safe to leave the corresponding features uninstalled.

Comment: Thank you man, i've already installed JBossAS Tools and now can add my WildFly server ^^. Regards.

Comment: But you will need something like this manual and its suggested update-site: http://hiplab.mc.vanderbilt.edu/projects/soempi/eclipse_jboss_tools_install.html to actually find those **Abridged JBoss Tools** (substitute indigo with kepler or which ever Eclipse you use), They are not in the market as such.

Answer (score 4):

On Eclipse Luna, I did this:

- From main menu, select `Help` -> `Eclipse Marketplace...`
- Type `JBoss Tools` in the search box
- Select the `JBoss Tools` plugin and click `Install`
- Give it a moment to figure out all the features in the plugin
- Deselect all features
- Find the feature named `JBossAS Tools` and select it
- Next, Next, Finish (actually it's a bit more contrived than
  that but you'll manage)

On Eclipse Mars this is even simpler, as the JBoss Server Adapter is installed by default.